# When is ResultIterable necessary?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pickle, rdd

[`groupByKey`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.groupByKey.html) function for RDDs returns pairs of type `(<key_type>, ResultIterable)`. While I was trying to understand the reason why the `ResultIterable` class exist, I found the following docstring in the [class definition](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/resultiterable.py#L31):

> A special result iterable. This is used because the standard iterator can not be pickled

#### Question 1: Why is this iterator "pickleable" and the standard one is not?

I even tried to locally re-write the `groupByKey` function, but commenting the final `.mapValues(ResultIterable)`, basically [copy-pasting](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/rdd.html#RDD.groupByKey) only the necessary code that would make the `groupByKey` function working:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.shuffle import Aggregator, ExternalMerger, \
    get_used_memory, ExternalSorter, ExternalGroupBy
import os
from pyspark.resultiterable import ResultIterable

sc = pyspark.SparkContext('local[*]')

def portable_hash(x):
    if 'PYTHONHASHSEED' not in os.environ:
        raise RuntimeError("Randomness of hash of string should be disabled via PYTHONHASHSEED")

    if x is None:
        return 0
    if isinstance(x, tuple):
        h = 0x345678
        for i in x:
            h ^= portable_hash(i)
            h *= 1000003
            h &= sys.maxsize
        h ^= len(x)
        if h == -1:
            h = -2
        return int(h)
    return hash(x)

def groupByKey(rdd, numPartitions=None, partitionFunc=portable_hash):
    def createCombiner(x):
        return [x]

    def mergeValue(xs, x):
        xs.append(x)
        return xs

    def mergeCombiners(a, b):
        a.extend(b)
        return a

    memory = rdd._memory_limit()
    serializer = rdd._jrdd_deserializer
    agg = Aggregator(createCombiner, mergeValue, mergeCombiners)

    def combine(iterator):
        merger = ExternalMerger(agg, memory * 0.9, serializer)
        merger.mergeValues(iterator)
        return merger.items()

    locally_combined = rdd.mapPartitions(combine, preservesPartitioning=True)
    shuffled = locally_combined.partitionBy(numPartitions, partitionFunc)

    def groupByKey(it):
        merger = ExternalGroupBy(agg, memory, serializer)
        merger.mergeCombiners(it)
        return merger.items()

    return shuffled.mapPartitions(groupByKey, True)#.mapValues(ResultIterable)
    
test_rdd = sc.parallelize([("a", 1), ("b", 1), ("a", 1)])
sorted(groupByKey(test_rdd).collect())
```

And this produces the expected result, that is

```
[('a', [1, 1]), ('b', [1])]
```

#### Question 2: starting from my UDF `groupByKey`, could you provide an example where the missing `.mapValues(ResultIterable)` becomes necessary?